# Can I have a separate thermostat for a wood boiler?

Tags: hvac, boiler

I want to wire a separate thermostat for my outdoor wood boiler so that just the furnace fan will come on without the propane kicking on. This is a Coleman furnace.

Is this possible and if so, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: Model number would be useful.

Comment: I have a wood boiler in this 9yr old house I purchased...it has 2 thermostats the bottom thermostat is just for my electric heat and air and the top thermostat is just for the wood boiler

Answer (score 2):

You don't offer much detail in your question, so it's difficult to determine exactly what you want to do.  If you're just looking for manual control you could just energize the `G` terminal on the furnace, which will run the fan in high speed mode (if the furnace has a variable speed motor). Most thermostats have a switch labeled `AUTO` and `FAN`. If you put the switch in the `FAN` position, the `G` terminal of the thermostat will be connected to the `R` terminal (meaning the `G` terminal is energized).

If you want automatic control, you might be able to use a thermostat that has multiple heating controls.  Then  you might be able to use the `W2` terminal of the thermostat to turn on the furnace fan, and the outdoor boiler.

Again, without more information it's difficult to tell you exactly what you can/should do.

Answer (score 1):

I Have an outside wood boiler. The circulating pump runs 24-7. I just replaced my old furnace last August with a new furnace that has a Lennox circuit board. With my old furnace, I added a White Rodgers relay so I could run two thermostats.

One thermostat ran the fan with the gas furnace on. The other thermostat only ran the fan. I could run the fan to circulate heat through the heat exchanger. Although this needs to be supervised because it does not shut off automatically. I also used the second thermostat to turn on the fan motor only to circulate cool air through the heat exchanger in the summer.

The wood boiler pump circulates cool water through the Pex pipe and through the heat exchanger. Because the ground is colder and the Pex pipe is underground several feet and using the heat exchanger to blow forced air through it in the summer it is like having an air conditioner in the house.

With the new furnace, I could not find any information on how to hook the Lennox circuit board so the fan would run alone without turning on the furnace. I have been working on reconfiguring the circuit board since I bought the new furnace. Today I felt confident enough to go down to the basement and implement and reconfigure the circuit board. I had a backup plan in case I blew the circuit board, a new one in overnight.

Two different speeds:

- #1) 24 volt Heat connector has a brown wire from the fan relay fan motor.
- #2) 24 volt Cool connector has a yellow wire from the fan relay motor different speed.

Setting up two thermostats separately to #1 and #2 could burn up the motor if put on at the same time. What I did was I disconnected the yellow wire out of the 24-volt cool connector. I bought a jumper connector and connected the #1) heat brown wire to the #2) cool connector. I put the yellow wire in park. I hooked up my second thermostat wires to (R) 24 volt and (Y) cooling on the circuit board.

It works. If I want to run the gas furnace it will run off the #1 thermostat. If I want to run just the fan it will work on the #2 thermostat. I can even do a setback on the thermostats, and they can even overlap. I do not know about the long-term effects on the furnace.